# Console.ReadKey vs Console.ReadLine with a Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, console, garbage-collection

The following code is a well known example to show the difference between a debug and release build:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In TimerCallback: " + DateTime.Now);
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

If you run this with a debug configuration, the timer will output the current time every two seconds. The `GC.Collect` doesn't have any effect because the compiler artificially extends the life of the `Timer t` variable. In a release configuration, the timer will execute only once. The `GC.Collect` will garbage collect the `t` variable and that's it.

This all works like it should. The strange thing is, when you change the line Console.ReadLine to Console.ReadKey *both* configurations run the timer every two seconds.

What is the difference between Console.ReadKey and Console.ReadLine? I understood [from the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx) that Console.ReadKey blocks the thread issuing the ReadKey method. But the GC.Collect still fires..

**Why is the lifetime of `Timer t` extended by blocking the main thread?**

### Update

When using .NET 3.5, this behavior won't occur!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Console.ReadKey()` method locks the `Console.InternalSyncObject` whereas the `Console.ReadLine()` method does not. When the `TimerCallBack()` method tries to write to the `Console` the `Thread` waits because the `Console.InternalSyncObject` is still locked. Therefore `GC.Collect()` is never called. As soon as you hit a key the lock is released and `GC.Collect()` is called.

I changed your code to the following which doesn't lock the `Console.InternalSyncObject` and it only beeps once in Release and every 2 seconds in Debug.

```
private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
{
    Console.Beep();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

The reason the Console.WriteLine() waits is because it tries to acquire a lock on the `Console.InternalSyncObject` when creating the `Console.Out` `TextWriter` for the first time.

Changing your code to the following works as expected as we create the `Console.Out` `TextWriter` before starting the timer.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loaded");
    Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In TimerCallback: " + DateTime.Now);
    GC.Collect();
}
```

This is due to a change in .NET 4.5. More info [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorony/archive/2012/09/12/console-readkey-net-4-5-changes-may-deadlock-your-system.aspx)

Comment: I noticed that adding a Console.WriteLine before creating the timer also fixes the behavior. It has something to do with Read locking the Stream so you can't create a Write.

Comment: Just added more info as you were commenting. I found the Console attempts to acquire a lock when creating the Out TextWriter for the first time

Comment: Any ideas about why .NET 3.5 does things differently? Probably something with async/await/TPL..

Comment: I just checked. ReadKey() and it's overloads don't lock the `InternalSyncObject` in .NET 3.5

Comment: Cool :) I new that the Console implemented some locking mechanism but never studied how it actually worked.

Comment: It doesn't lock in .NET 4.0 either. Looks like the change was in .NET 4.5. I wonder why MS changed it?

Comment: @alexw .NET 4.0 is an in place update of .NET 4.5. As soon as you install .NET 4.0 on a PC, it will have the race condition.